# Windows cmd: Copy over entire directory *including* parent directory. Solution without specifying same parent directory name

Tags: windows, copy, cmd, xcopy, robocopy

In Windows, how do you copy an entire directory, INCLUDING the parent directory folder?

For instance, let's say we have the directory c:\Folder and want to copy it over to d: .

The only way right now would be:
xcopy /E c:\Folder d:\Folder

Is there a way to do this without specifying the same end directory (Folder)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm told that an application called RoboCopy can do it, however, I believe it's part of a series of server 2003/2008 tools -- I can't speak to its capabilities or whether it will work on your version of Windows.  That said, there are a set of tools (basically UNIX commands ported to DOS) [located here](http://openetwork.com/berk.html) that will do what you need -- specifically the "cp" command.  My apologies for not being able to assist further.